# ASP.NET Core how to remove specific CSS and JavaScript files in release

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core-2.1

My problem is that when I made the website it functioned as it sould but when I put it on the server this block of css and js is shown:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<meta name="x-stylesheet-fallback-test" content="" class="sr-only" /><script>!function(a,b,c,d){var e,f=document,g=f.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"),h=g[g.length-1].previousElementSibling,i=f.defaultView&&f.defaultView.getComputedStyle?f.defaultView.getComputedStyle(h):h.currentStyle;if(i&&i[a]!==b)for(e=0;e<c.length;e++)f.write('<link href="'+c[e]+'" '+d+"/>")}("position","absolute",["\/lib\/bootstrap\/dist\/css\/bootstrap.min.css"], "rel=\u0022stylesheet\u0022 ");</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.min.css?v=kHvJwvVAK1eJLN4w8xygUR3nbvlLmRwi5yr-OuAO90E" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css" />
<meta name="x-stylesheet-fallback-test" content="" class="k-common-test-class" /><script>!function(a,b,c,d){var e,f=document,g=f.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"),h=g[g.length-1].previousElementSibling,i=f.defaultView&&f.defaultView.getComputedStyle?f.defaultView.getComputedStyle(h):h.currentStyle;if(i&&i[a]!==b)for(e=0;e<c.length;e++)f.write('<link href="'+c[e]+'" '+d+"/>")}("opacity","0",["\/lib\/kendo-ui\/styles\/kendo.common-nova.min.css"], "rel=\u0022stylesheet\u0022 ");</script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.nova.min.css" />
<meta name="x-stylesheet-fallback-test" content="" class="k-theme-test-class" /><script>!function(a,b,c,d){var e,f=document,g=f.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"),h=g[g.length-1].previousElementSibling,i=f.defaultView&&f.defaultView.getComputedStyle?f.defaultView.getComputedStyle(h):h.currentStyle;if(i&&i[a]!==b)for(e=0;e<c.length;e++)f.write('<link href="'+c[e]+'" '+d+"/>")}("opacity","0",["\/lib\/kendo-ui\/styles\/kendo.nova.min.css"], "rel=\u0022stylesheet\u0022 ");</script>
    
    

    
    
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
        </script>
<script>(window.jQuery||document.write("\u003Cscript src=\u0022\/lib\/jquery\/dist\/jquery.min.js\u0022 crossorigin=\u0022anonymous\u0022 integrity=\u0022sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV\u002BrXbYlF2cqB8txI\/8aZajjp4Bqd\u002BV6D5IgvKT\u0022\u003E\u003C\/script\u003E"));</script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
<script>(window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal||document.write("\u003Cscript src=\u0022\/lib\/bootstrap\/dist\/js\/bootstrap.min.js\u0022 crossorigin=\u0022anonymous\u0022 integrity=\u0022sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa\u0022\u003E\u003C\/script\u003E"));</script>
        <script src="/js/site.min.js?v=47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU"></script>

        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js">
        </script>
<script>(window.kendo||document.write("\u003Cscript src=\u0022\/lib\/kendo-ui\/js\/kendo.all.min.js\u0022\u003E\u003C\/script\u003E"));</script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js">
        </script>
<script>(kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']||document.write("\u003Cscript src=\u0022\/lib\/kendo-ui\/js\/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js\u0022\u003E\u003C\/script\u003E"));</script>
```

I did chek my layout file and it has the enviroment exclude tag for Develepment, Staging and Production for both css and js separately.

```html
<environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="k-common-test-class"
              asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="k-theme-test-class"
              asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />

    <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
            asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
            asp-fallback-test-class="k-common-test-class"
            asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
            asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
            asp-fallback-test-class="k-theme-test-class"
            asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />
    </environment>
```

```html
<environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

        @*  Place Kendo UI scripts after jQuery *@
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.kendo">
        </script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']">
        </script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

        @*  Place Kendo UI scripts after jQuery *@
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.kendo">
        </script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']">
        </script>
    </environment>
```

So why does the excluded code show up when I publish my website?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your final markup appears to be working properly so I'm a bit confused about your exact problem. You have defined two environmental conditionals, but both appear to have exact same markup therefore will render same on both development and production/staging which makes no sense.

First of all you want to define what will appear in development, this should be local unminified versions without fallbacks or versioning:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-nova.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.nova.css" />
</environment>
```

Then you define your production markup which can use CDNs, fallbacks, minification and versioning.

```
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="k-common-test-class"
          asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="k-theme-test-class"
          asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />
</environment>
```

Given environment variables are set properly on target systems, first block will be available in development and the second one in staging/production.

Comment: Yeah I do have the include and all, but my problem is that when I publish my website it still includes the excluded stuff, or rahter I don't want to siplay the excluded stuff in release